# ServiceStack and OAuth

Tags: service, oauth, stack

How can I use ServiceStack's Credentials authentication to implement a custom OAuth2 solution? I am trying to use it so I don't have to use 3rd party providers like Google.

Answer (score 0):

The `CredentialsAuthProvider` is not an OAuth2 provider, it enables a conventional UserName / Password Login and uses ServiceStack's built-in `/register` Service for Registration/SignUp.

The [HttpBenchmarks LiveDemo](http://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net/) explains how to enable both [Credentials Auth as OAuth Providers](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#authentication) in the same application.